# Delete everything before first pattern match with sed/awk

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Let's say I have a line looking like this:

```
/Users/random/354765478/Tests/StoreTests/Base64Tests.swift
```

In this example, I would like to get the result:

```
Tests/StoreTests/Base64Tests.swift
```

How can I do if I want to get everything before the first pattern match (either `Sources` or `Tests`) using **sed** or **awk**?

I am using `sed 's/^.*\(Tests.*\).*$/\1/'` right now but it's falling:

```
echo '/Users/random/354765478/Tests/StoreTests/Base64Tests.swift' | sed 's/^.*\(Tests\)/\1/'
Tests.swift
```

Here's another example using **Sources** (which seems to work):

```
echo '/Users/random/741672469/Sources/Store/StoreDataSource.swift' | sed 's/^.*\(Sources\)/\1/'
Sources/Store/StoreDataSource.swift
```

I would like to get everything before the first, and not the last **Sources** or **Tests** pattern match.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `sed 's%.*/\(Tests/\)%\1%'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I do if I want to get everything before the first pattern match (either `Sources` or `Tests`).

Easier to use a `grep -o` here:

```bash
grep -Eo '(Sources|Tests)/.*' file

Tests/StoreTests/Base64Tests.swift
Sources/Store/StoreDataSource.swift

# where input file is
cat file

/Users/random/354765478/Tests/StoreTests/Base64Tests.swift
/Users/random/741672469/Sources/Store/StoreDataSource.swift
```

**Breakdown:**

- Regex pattern `(Sources|Tests)/.*` match any text that starts with `Sources/` or `Tests/` until end of the line.
- `-E`: enables extended regex mode
- `-o`: prints only matched text instead of full line

---

Alternatively you may use this `awk` as well:

```bash
awk 'match($0, /(Sources|Tests)\/.*/) {
   print substr($0, RSTART)
}' file

Tests/StoreTests/Base64Tests.swift
Sources/Store/StoreDataSource.swift
```

---

Or this `sed`:

```bash
sed -E 's~.*/((Sources|Tests)/.*)~\1~' file

Tests/StoreTests/Base64Tests.swift
Sources/Store/StoreDataSource.swift
```

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples please try following GNU `grep`. This will look for very first match of `/Sources` OR `/Tests` and then print values from these strings to till end of the value.

```bash
grep -oP '^.*?\/\K(Sources|Tests)\/.*' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's~([^/]*/)+((Tests|Sources).*)~\2~' input_file
Tests/StoreTests/Base64Tests.swift
```

Answer (score 1):

> would like to get everything before the first, and not the last
> Sources or Tests pattern match.

First thing is to understand reason of that, you are using

```
sed 's/^.*\(Tests.*\).*$/\1/'
```

observe that `*` is greedy, i.e. it will match as much as possible, therefore it will always pick *last* `Tests`, if it would be non-greedy it would find first `Tests` but `sed` does not support this, if you are using linux there is good chance that you have `perl` command which does support that, let `file.txt` content be

```
/Users/random/354765478/Tests/StoreTests/Base64Tests.swift
```

then

```
perl -p -e 's/^.*?(Tests.*)$/\1/' file.txt
```

gives output

```
Tests/StoreTests/Base64Tests.swift
```

Explanation: `-p -e` means engage sed-like mode, alterations in regular expression made: brackets no longer require escapes, first `.*` (greedy) changed to `.*?` (non-greedy), last `.*` deleted as superfluous (observe that capturing group will always extended to end of line)

*(tested in perl 5, version 30, subversion 0)*